# Output doens't come out as expected

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I tried to add an boolean array that will store current status of user.
This is my array:

```
bool enterStatus[5];
```

Later in the code, i will check the array based on the id i get and then if the id is false, set it true and vice versa.

Assume the id is 1,

```
if(enterStatus[id] == true){
  enterStatus[id] = false;
} if(enterStatus[id] == false){
  enterStatus[id] = true;
}
Serial.print(enterStatus[id]);
```

That's what i try.
The output i get:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

I want the the loop output to be:

```
1010101010101010101010101
```

Where did i do wrong? please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `else` before the second `if`

Comment: tq sir for the answer. youre right. but why adding else changing the output 101010101?

Comment: @user16813339, its because the code execeutes from top to below. You set the value of `enterStatus[id]` to `false` and then directly after you check if it is `false` and set it to `true` again

Comment: i see thank you for answering this post. sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @user16813339 there aren't silly questions, never be afraid to ask if you don't fully understand something

Comment: tq very much :)

Comment: @user16813339, Alessandro is right. No questions are stupid :) You could also try to answer your own question to help other people who have the same issue in the future.

Comment: Just replace all that with `enterStatus[id] = !enterStatus[id] ;`

Comment: Oh for lack of a debugger and sixty seconds spent using it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `if`'s are wrong as your check if `true` and set to `false`, then if `false` (which it's now gaurenteed to be), will be set to `true`. please put an `else` before the second `if`

Comment: tq very much sir

Comment: don't worry I always do dumb things like this :)